# Populate an Array with a Comma Delimited String Content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My app uses a web service in which you scan a food item which returns a UPC number. I feed this number into the web service, and i get all the details about that specific food. I grabbed the "ingredients" and turned it into an array called "ingredients".

This is the value of my array:

```
  ingredientsArray = dataDictionary[@"nf_ingredient_statement"];
```

When I NSLog my [ingredients description] value, it looks like this:

Distilled Vinegar, Water, #1 Grade Mustard Seed, Salt, Turmeric, Paprika, Spice, Natural Flavors and Garlic Powder.

My question is how can I turn that string into an array which will populate the table view?

Comment: How did you turn it into an array?

Comment: i used the web service to turn the returned value of "ingredients" into an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to turn a comma-separated string into an array, here is how you do it, assuming the string is separated by a comma and then a space.

```
NSString *exampleString = @"one, two, three";
NSArray *exampleArray = [exampleString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Produces:

```
2014-08-25 23:01:26.561 Testing[60889:3946435] (
    one,
    two,
    three
)
```

I'm not confident based on your post/comment if you're dealing with an array or a string, but if I were you I would NSLog(@"%@", [ingredientsArray class]); to see what class the object you think you have is.